# Cosmos group by across partitions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to query a collection to get the count of items and group by two columns; let's call them X and Y. I'm running the query in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer v1.18.1.

The issue I have is that the query is across partitions in the collection. This is the query and the error below it.

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS ItemCount, c.X, c.Y
FROM (
   SELECT c.X, c.Y, c.A
   FROM c
   WHERE c.Deleted = false AND c.State = 'Open'
) C
GROUP BY c.X, c.Y
```

Error:

```
Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE <aggregateFunc>' for aggregates.
```

Where do I place the `VALUE` keyword in the query?

Additional information:

1. The partition key is `/ItemId`
2. An example document is

```
{
   "ItemId": "BSD-02930",
   "A": "GB2825",
   "X": "SAM",
   "Y": "WAN",
}
```

Comment: You just need to add SELECT VALUE COUNT(1)

Comment: I tried that, but it produces a syntax error: `incorrect syntax near 'AS'`. :/

Comment: can you add a sample doc

Comment: Are you running this query via an SDK, or directly in the data explorer? Any difference?

Comment: can you do something like this SELECT COUNT(1) AS ItemCount, c.Y , c.X
FROM c
WHERE c.Deleted = "false" AND c.State = 'Open'
GROUP BY c.X, c.Y?

Comment: Given that the storage explorer is deprecated for Cosmos access, can you try in the Azure portal's data explorer?